# How to iterate inner element in Array<any> variable in typescript??

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

**Service.ts**

```
 getApiTrace(name: string, firstDate: string, lastDate: string, pageSize: number, index: number) {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:10061/dataList?appName=' + name + '&fromdate=' + firstDate + '&toDate=' + lastDate +  "&pageSize=" + pageSize + "&index=" + index).map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

these service returns **json** as:

```
{
   "size": 3,
   "dataResults": [
       {
           "name": "chetan",
           "city": "vadodara",
           "rank": 56 
       },
       {
           "name": "kishan",
           "city": "kutch",
           "rank": 23 
       },
       {  
           "name": "chinmay",
           "city": "surat",
           "rank": 34 
       }
   ]
}
```

and it **stored in** `data:Array<any>`

Now If i have to get only names into HTML then we can write it by `{{data?.dataResults}}` into for loop. but how can i write it into **Typescript** to get all names into **String[ ]**.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use,

```
const names: string[] = data.dataResults.map((result) => result.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tries something like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {



  myarray: string[];

  constructor(private _myService : MyService) {

  }


  //Page Load
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this._myService.getApiTrace(/*params*/).then((resp)=>{
     this.myarray = res.data. dataResults.map(xx=> xx. name);

}).catch()
  }


}
```

now your myarray is full with the names of all items

hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

use the ng dirrective `*ngFor`

in this way: 
`<div *ngFor="let elem of data">{{elem.dataResults.name}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.map` function to get the array of names,

For eg,

```
let jsonObj = {
    "size": 3,
    "dataResults": [
        {
            "name": "chetan",
            "city": "vadodara",
            "rank": 56
        },
        {
            "name": "kishan",
            "city": "kutch",
            "rank": 23
        },
        {
            "name": "chinmay",
            "city": "surat",
            "rank": 34
        }
    ]
};

let names: string[] = jsonObj.dataResults.map((namesObj) => namesObj.name);
alert(names);
```

A working demo is available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20jsonObj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22dataResults%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22chetan%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22city%22%3A%20%22vadodara%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22rank%22%3A%2056%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22kishan%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22city%22%3A%20%22kutch%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22rank%22%3A%2023%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22chinmay%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22city%22%3A%20%22surat%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22rank%22%3A%2034%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20names%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20jsonObj.dataResults.map((namesObj)%20%3D%3E%20namesObj.name)%3B%0D%0Aalert(names)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Frontend framework you're using, you should have a way to loop through `data?.dataResults`.

If you're using Angular 
`*ngFor i of data?.dataResults`
where i.name holds each of then names that can be displayed in the HTML